# passing method as parameter and getting error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, reflection

I am getting error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

here is my code

```
public class ManageEnrollmentTest {
    @Test
    public void Test_Filter_By_Active() throws Exception{

        assertTrue("Log in failed", Helper.LoginTest());

        assertTrue("Activation failed", fitlerResults("Active"));

    }

    private Boolean fitlerResults(String dS){
        Boolean isOk = false;
        try{
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("$('#dType').val('36').change().trigger(\"liszt:updated\");;");

            WebElement findButton = driver.findElement(By.id("findDealersBtn"));
            findButton.click();

            Method method = ManageEnrollmentTest.class.getMethod("verifyActive");           //////// Error
            isOk = loadEnrollmentTablePageByPageAndVerify(method);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            isOk = false;
        }
        return isOk;
    }

    private Boolean loadEnrollmentTablePageByPageAndVerify(Method method){
        return (Boolean)method.invoke(this);
    }

    //browse throw all dealers that are currently on page
    private Boolean verifyActive(){
        ....
        ....
        return isOk;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does your error point to?

Answer (score 3):

Your method is private but [getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...%29) only returns public method.You need to use [getDeclaredMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...%29).

`getMethod()` - *Returns a Method object that reflects the specified **public** member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.*